# Count multiple columns by removing duplicates in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a large data but they are similar to the following data:

```html
df1<-read.table(text=" A1 A2 A3 A4

Rose,Sarah Rose,Sarah Smith,Roger Emily,Cute
Rose,Sarah Emily,Cute Smith,Roger Emily,Cute
Emily,Cute Rose,Sarah Smith,Roger Dave,Yellow
Emily,Cute John,Price Hana,Pipe Dave,Yellow
John,Price Rose,Sarah Hana,Pipe Dave,Yellow
John,Price John,Price Hana,Pipe Dave,Yellow
John,Price Rose,Sarah Smith,Roger Dave,Yellow

",header=TRUE)
```

I want to count names once according to the columns. Here is the intended output.

```html
Column     Name Time
A1,A2,A4  Emily,Cute    3
A1,A2     Rose,Sarah    2
A1,A2    John,Price      2
A3      Smith,Roger   1
A3      Hana,Pipe     1
A4      Dave,Yellow  1
Total    6            10
```

Can we do it in R? Th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df1 %>%
 pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Column", values_to = "Name") %>%
 group_by(Name, Column) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 group_by(Name) %>%
 summarise(Column = toString(Column),
           Time = n())

  Name        Column      Time
  <fct>       <chr>      <int>
1 Emily,Cute  A1, A2, A4     3
2 John,Price  A1, A2         2
3 Rose,Sarah  A1, A2         2
4 Hana,Pipe   A3             1
5 Smith,Roger A3             1
6 Dave,Yellow A4             1
```

If you want exact results, also with the totals:

```
df1 %>%
 pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Column", values_to = "Name") %>%
 group_by(Name, Column) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 group_by(Name) %>%
 summarise(Column = toString(Column),
           Time = n()) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
 add_row() %>%
 mutate(Name = ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()), n_distinct(Name)-1, Name),
        Column = ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()), "Total", Column),
        Time = ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()), sum(Time, na.rm = TRUE), Time)) %>%
 select(Column, Name, Time)

  Column     Name         Time
  <chr>      <chr>       <int>
1 A1, A2, A4 Emily,Cute      3
2 A1, A2     John,Price      2
3 A1, A2     Rose,Sarah      2
4 A3         Hana,Pipe       1
5 A3         Smith,Roger     1
6 A4         Dave,Yellow     1
7 Total      6              10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to "long" then summarize by Name. (Same approach as dplyr answer)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

long <- melt(df1[, r := 1:.N], 'r')
long[, .(Column = toString(unique(variable)), 
         Time = uniqueN(variable)), 
     by = .(Name = value)]

#           Name     Column Time
# 1:  Rose,Sarah     A1, A2    2
# 2:  Emily,Cute A1, A2, A4    3
# 3:  John,Price     A1, A2    2
# 4: Smith,Roger         A3    1
# 5:   Hana,Pipe         A3    1
# 6: Dave,Yellow         A4    1
```